# How can I change my input to accept a string from the user? Currently my program will only work with a char value

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am almost complete this program, however I need to change it to where a user can input a string instead of only a char. Currently it will only accept a char, and adding anything more will terminate the program abruptly. I have used strings in the past, but this assignment is a little different. I am required to input anything a user types, and see if that can be converted into only the letters included in the array. These are `{ 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'h', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'w'}` If the user enters anything other than the alphabet, it should give an error, saying to only accept words. If the user enters only alphabet, then the program should check whether it can be written in the `reducedAlphabet` array. If it cannot, it should say no. If all the input can be converted into those specific alphabetic characters, my program will output "Ae".

I will attach some examples for how I want the program to run. I have tried creating a loop that will validate each character the user types and see if it is a letter, however I have had trouble making it. What would be a good way for me to validate a string the user types, and see if it will fit in the alphabet? How can I also make sure that the input does not matter whether they are capital or not?

Here is a basic pseudocode:

```
Enter  String: >$5&

Error.  Only Words. Please try again.

Enter  String: >-23

Error. Only  Words. Please try again.

Enter  String: >abc12

Error. Only   Words. Please try again.

Enter  String: >12asd

Error. Only   Words. Please try again.

Enter  String: >Talk

No

Enter  String: >mE

Ae

Enter  String: >yOu

No

Enter  String: >nOW

Ae
```

Example program

```
       #include <iostream>
       #include <cctype>

    using namespace std;

    int searchList(char[],int, char);              //Function prototype



    int main()
    {
     char again;                                    //Will hold a y or n
     
     char input;                                    //Will hold the users input
     
     
     int max = 13;
     char reducedAlphabet[max] = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'h', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'w'};         //Declaration of alphabet
     int results;

     
    
     do
       {
        cout << "Enter any input " << endl;
        cin >> input;
        
        if (isalpha(input)) 
        {
            results = searchList(reducedAlphabet, max, input);
            
         {
            if (results == -1)
                 cout << "No " << endl;
            else
                cout << "Ae " << endl;
        }
        }
       
        else
        {
            cout << "Error. Words only. Please try again. " << endl;
        }
                    
         cout << "Do you want to input another value? (Y/N) " << endl;
         cin >> again;
        
    }while (toupper(again) == 'Y');
    
         
     return 0;
    }

    int searchList(char *list, int num, char value)
    {
         int index = 0;
         int position = -1;
         bool found = false;
                
             while (index < num && !found && index<=value)
                {
                    if (list[index] == value)
                    {
                        found = true;
                        position = index;
                    }
                    index++;                                        
                }return position;    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the program only reads one character is because your input variable is of type `char`

Since you declared `char input`, cin will only read one character.

You should instead use std::string (can be simply string since you used `using namespace std;` earlier in your code), so that cin will read in an entire string.

You'll also want to update the searchList function to either take a string as the 3rd argument, or call searchList over all the characters in the inputted string.

```
...
int main()
{
 char again;                                    //Will hold a y or n
 
 char input;  //<-- should be string input;
 
 ...

 do
   {
    cout << "Enter any input " << endl;
    cin >> input;
    
    if (isalpha(input)) //<-- you'll probably have to change this too, iirc isalpha only works on chars
    {
        results = searchList(reducedAlphabet, max, input); //<-- change this so that it either loops over each char of the string or takes in the whole string as input
        
     ...
 return 0;
}

int searchList(char *list, int num, char value)
...
```

If I were you, I'd probably change your main function so that it checks if each character is alphabetic, and also in the restricted alphabet, as it's easier than changing the searchList function.

Something like this will do the trick:

```
    ...
    cout << "Enter any input " << endl;
    cin >> input;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) { // loop over string
        if (!isalpha(input[i])) {              // check if ith character is alphabet
            cout << "Error. Words only. Please try again. " << endl;
            break;
        }

        // checks if ith character is in restricted alphabet
        results = searchList(reducedAlphabet, max, input[i]); 

        if (results == -1) {         // if not, print no and stop looping
             cout << "No " << endl;
             break;
        } else if (i == input.length() - 1) { 
            // if this is the last loop iteration and we haven't exited, then it's a success
            cout << "Ae " << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << "Do you want to input another value? (Y/N) " << endl;
    cin >> again;
    ...
```

I also noticed that your searcList function doesn't take into account capitalization: according to your test data, `mE` should work, but it doesn't because the E is capitalized. You should fix that too.

EDIT: Didn't realize this was part of your question too.
In terms of checking for capital and lowercase letters, you can check if the letter you are checking against is capital or lowercase. If it is capital, you can convert it to a lowercase character and then check if it matches any of the characters in your reduced alphabet.

Comment: Sweet, that helped a lot, thanks. There is one more thing I cannot fix, if I enter a string that matches the reduced alphabet, there is no output on the screen. It just asks if i want to enter again. Also when I change the 3rd parameter argument to a string, the program will not work.

Comment: Yeah, if you do this (changing the main function) you don't have to modify the searchList function to take in a string as input anymore. Not sure why it prints nothing if the string matches though, it worked in my testing. Can you make sure that you didn't accidentally remove the cin >> input line accidentally? I've also edited my answer to make it more clear where exactly my code fits in

Comment: Yea its weird, it will output properly if a single char matches though. I will play around with it and try some different things. Thanks a lot though, I would not have been able to figure this out myself haha.